# Single Docker Image with multiple Softwares or Separate images for separate software

Tags: image, docker

Need your expert advice before building my docker image. I have  a requirement where I want to install multiple programming languages in a docker image.  I have two options to proceed

(a) Install all the softwares together and build a single image which may be around 4GB.

(b) Install all the softwares separately and build a separate image for each software where I will have each image around 1GB.

Now question is if I want to use these images on a single machine to create multiple containers which will run in parallel then which option is better one, to have single image with bigger size or multiple images with smaller size?

Thanks in advance for your kind suggestions.

Regards

Mohtashim

Answer (score 1):

According to the Docker best practice, you have to put one service per image. This will allow you to have more finegraned service control. Look here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/